# Accidental Windows to Linux Overwrite

Tags: linux, windows-vista, partition-recovery

I wanted to install Linux for my system and was expecting it to dual-boot and I would have double OS in my system. But I ended up pressing the "Use Entire Disk..." option thing (Not 100% sure if that's what it said but it did say something about entire disk.) and now I can't get access to my Windows Vista OS. I do have a backup and I do not know if that will help but please tell me what I can do to fix it. I do have Test-Disk but I'm currently working out on how to use it, if any of you are willing to teach me on how to use it that would be great.

If any of you needs more information feel free to tell me and I'll gladly give them to you.

Comment: Since you say "I ended up overwriting the entire disk" - i think the chances of recovering Vista back on are very slim. Does your HDD have any of the windows data (NFTS / FAT) partitions now? Or are all the partitions now formatted to EXTx partition?

Comment: @Prasanna: I'm not sure to be honest. Can you tell me how to check? Also about the "I ended up overwriting the entire disk". That's the option I pressed when installing linux, it was more like "Use the Entire disk..." something like that.

Comment: Do you remember seeing a warning after selecting that "Use entire disk"? (If not, then I still assume Linux has only claimed the free space of the entire disk. (But [I might be wrong](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28009/what-is-the-difference-between-the-entire-partition-and-entire-disc)...) On the other hand: this being Vista, it's likely not a very large harddisk?)

Comment: Ok. Seems like you have given the entire disk to Linux and this is a "point of no-return" on recovery terms. If you have any Windows OS media with you then create partitions and install Windows onto one of the partitions (I think you would need about 60 GB) to comfortably install Windows 7. After you are done with that you will be able to install Linux. Don't use the entire HDD for your Windows OS Installation. For step by step instruction follow [link] (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52291-partition-hard-drive-windows-7-install.html)

Comment: @Arjan: As far as I'm aware when I clicked the option it just started installing.

Comment: @Prasanna: Okay I will try this. Oh is the backup any help at all at this point?

Comment: Without more detail about *which* Linux distribution, the version and all, I guess people can only guess what happened.

Comment: @Arjan: How can I get the Linux distribution and all that other stuff?

Comment: @Prasanna, nice (very nice) you're willing to go to great lengths to help. But note that Stack Exchange sites (including Super User) were never meant to be some personal help forums. All questions should ideally also have some value for future visitors who have the same problem. Solving the problem through Skype or email is not helping trying to achieve that? Also, other answerers might miss details that you've shared among the two of you, and waste their time trying to help.

Comment: @Arjan I agree with you. At some point it becomes impossible to help over comments. And i also found somewhere in SU that comments should not be used like "chat". So i've no choice... Sorry.

Comment: Well, @Prasanna, your choice *could* be to not let people pollute Super User with questions that lack detail. But that's up to you. (And again, it's very nice that you want to help. But since you wrote *"Even I'm a new user"*, I just don't think this is what Stack Exchange sites are about.) If the two of you find a solution, please post that as an answer here.

Comment: Before you do anything else, make a backup of your hard drive exactly as it is now. That way, no matter what goes wrong in your recovery efforts, you can always get back to where you are now.

Comment: @Arjan The issue is resolved. I'm posting that as an answer as per your request _"If the two of you find a solution, please post that as an answer here"_. Thanks for your comment **"Without more detail about which Linux distribution, the version and all, I guess people can only guess what happened"** which motivated me to get to know more about the issue -off the network - of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RepeaterCreeper(RC) had a system with Microsoft Vista OS.  By installing Debian linux, the entire HDD had only two linux partitions (`\` and `swap`) and no trace of Windows installation. (I confirmed this by using `fdisk -l` command in linux). HDD was 160GB.
RC has a Win 7 DVD to install MS Win 7. There was an issue with the installation of Win 7. There was this following error **"Load Driver & Missing CD/DVD drive device driver"**  not allowing to continue the installation.  USB installation media was one among the suggested solutions on the internet.
I pointed the following [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuC83DEdwu0) to fix it. RC downloaded and installed the tool and made a USB installation media as per the YouTube video using his other PC.
Once the USB was ready, we installed Win 7 - making a 80GB HDD partition for Windows installation. This is what RC wanted. RC was informed that **"Live"** linux distros can be used to try linux before he would want to install anything on his PC.
Note: All these actions happened off-line (on GMail chat over two days) since RC did not have enough reps to enter chat on `SUPERUSER` - Hence no track of these events on comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could mess around with repartitioning, installing windows, fixing bootloader etc, but since you still have a pretty clean install... I would start over again.

First install your Windows. Make sure you only create a sized partition that you want to assign to Windows and leave the other space unformatted. Continue with the installation and then start your Linux install.

Make sure you use the FREE SPACE instead of the entire disk.

Bootloaders should work for both Windows and Linux, you may want to change the default system to Windows if you like... and you can then start restoring your stuff from backups.

Comment: *"since you still have a pretty clean install"* -- er, it's Windows Vista. I doubt that's a fresh install? Re-installing relies on being very sure the backup is okay. (Though trying to save the data on disk will be very hard, I agree.)

Comment: The clean install is the Linux that overwrote the Vista. Backups can be verified using the current Linux installation.